# Set PROPID_Q_JOURNAL for a created MSMQ queue

Tags: c#, msmq

I need to set the default `PROPID_Q_JOURNAL` property for a queue that I am creating with `MessageQueue.Create`.

There is no provided overload for setting this property?

This is the property, on the queue, that I want to set.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [MessageQueue.UseJournalQueue Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.usejournalqueue(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I have updated the question to be more specific. I want to set the default journal attribute for the queue.

Comment: Isn't that what MessageQueue.UseJournalQueue does? Once you've created the queue, set the property.

Comment: that property just tags a message as using journal on the next send. it doesn't actually update the default queue definition to always use journal, unless you know a way to subsequently save that property to the queue definition?

Comment: The definition says: "Setting this property modifies the Message Queuing queue. Therefore, any other MessageQueue instances are affected by the change." Sounds like the change should persist.